# How to use two headsets on one sound card

Tags: audio, headset, audio-streaming, mixer

I have two headsets (so headphone + microphone) and I would like to use both of them at the same time on my laptop. Is it possible to use two Y-connectors, one for sound and one for audio-streaming?

What I want to be able to do is basically to have a video chat with my parents, that are sitting at one computer and give them a headset each.

Comment: that would work with the earphones, but they would need to share the microphone. If the audio card only has one mic input, you cannot successfully use two mics. Try looking at USB headset solutions

Comment: You may be best to give them a set of headphones each, without a microphone. This way, you can use a stereo splitter or a y cable. Then, plug in a microphone and position it between them !

Answer (score 1):

You could use a Y-splitter. You basically plug in two inputs into one input or output jack. In my personal experience, i lost a lot of gain, to the point that I couldn't hear anything. However, they do make certain splitters specifically for headphones, such as the Belkin Rockstar, which I've been told works very well.